# Is video content including an unnamed patient's face HIPAA compliant?

Tags: privacy, medical

In a conference setting, practicing doctors may show video of their patients receiving treatment or undergoing an evaluation. The videos often include the patient's face, but are never named. These videos are shown to the audience, which includes mostly other practicing medical professionals and researchers. Under what circumstances is use of this video in this context HIPAA complaint? Is it by default, because of the scientific setting, or must patient consent be acquired? What if the lecture is recorded and offered to non-attending medical professionals? Offered to the general public?

---

Since I'm asking about HIPAA, this is clearly a question about United States Jurisdictions.

Comment: [Interesting related topic about video recording *in* hospitals.](http://www.thie.com/reducing_your_risk/risk_management_resources/sample_policies_procedures_and_forms/Video%20and%20audio%20recording%20in%20hospitals.pdf)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the patient in question agreed to be filmed during the evaluation (and signed a piece of paper stating that fact). If the patient didn't agree to the camera the doctor would wait for the next patient who does agree to the filming.

Comment: Check the HHS.gov website about health information privacy. https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/privacy/laws-regulations/index.html